# Reduced master equation for a multistable Hamiltonian dynamical system

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stochastic-processes, hamiltonian-mechanics

I am looking for rigorous results on the derivation of a reduced master equation for a (possibly stochastic) Hamiltonian dynamical system with a coercive potential energy term with multiple local minima. A state within a certain energy range will be most of the time in one of the valleys corresponding to the local minima and will at irregular times transit near saddle points between these.

There should be a limiting situation where the dynamics can be reduced to that of a master equation on the set of minimizers with random transitions. Surely this problem has received attention not only by physicists....